# Generalizations of Fitting subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

The Fitting subgroup of a group $G$ has two generalizations; one of them is $F^*(G)$ and the other is‎ $\tilde{F‎‎}(G)‎‎$. The last one is defined by $\phi(G)\subset \tilde{F‎‎}(G)‎‎$ and‎ $\tilde{F‎‎}(G)‎‎/ \phi(G)=\operatorname{Soc}(G/ \phi(G))$ ‎‪‪[V.I. Murashka, A.F. Vasil,ev, On partially conjugate-permutable subgroups of finite groups]. But I do not have access to the sources presented in this paper; I was wondering if you'd mind introducing me English resources correspond to this issue.

Answer (score 4):

A good reference is the book "Finite group Theory" of M. Aschbacher.
Chapter 11 is devoted to the generalized Fitting subgroup $F^*(G)$ of $G$,
and is quite detailed. The second one, $\tilde{F}(G)$ has been introduced by
Peter Schmid (the reference is in German, I know, but it is discussed in
Aschbacher's book and papers as well). Actually, I think that the paper of
Murashka and Vasil’ev (which is in English) gives already good information
on both generalized Fitting subgroups.

For further details see also here: [Minimal normal subgroups of a finite group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32145/minimal-normal-subgroups-of-a-finite-group).